# I'm having an issue adding a heroku.app url on azure app registration authorization adding it as a reply url

Tags: heroku, azure-active-directory, azureportal, msal.js

i'm trying to add my app url https://microsoftlogintest.herokuapp.com/ to the reply url of an app registration on azure ad but when I try to save I get this error

```
Failed to update ad-test application. Error detail: Your reply url contains prohibited words or prohibited domains. [RD7BlhMHT6VLcC9fUyhqEp]
```

[error message on azure portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41sdF.png)

Comment: Have you tried adding it through the Authentication tab of the app registration in the portal? It might give you a better error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try removing the word "microsoft" from your subdomain.